# MySQL CrossTab and remove duplicates

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table in MySQL that has students entered for every year they are registered.  I want to produce a query that will show nnn students born in yyyy for academic year ending aaaa.  I got that query working pretty quickly but the part that is stumping me is that I have some duplicate entries in the database that I need to reject from my totals.

Here is my query so far.  And, as I say, I know that it's allowing duplicate values in for some years.

```
SELECT COUNT(YEAR(birthdate)) as YearCount, YEAR(birthdate) as BirthYear, AcadYearEnding 
FROM Enrollment 
GROUP BY AcadYearEnding 
ORDER BY AcadYearEnding, BirthYear
```

The results end up looking like (if I put in a WHERE clause to restrict to a specific student):

```
YearCount   BirthYear   AcadYearEnding
1             2007          2012
2             2007          2013
1             2007          2014
1             2007          2015
```

This is the query with the WHERE clause that generated the data above ... but I eventually will remove the WHERE clause to show all students but without duplicate entries for any of the students.

```
SELECT COUNT(YEAR(birthdate)) as YearCount, YEAR(birthdate) as BirthYear, AcadYearEnding 
FROM Enrollment 
WHERE StudentId=16183
GROUP BY AcadYearEnding 
ORDER BY AcadYearEnding, BirthYear
```

Given my where clause is restricting to a single student, I know the 2013 entry is the result of an extra row in the database (and doing clean-up on the data isn't an option, we need to restrict it in the query).

I tried doing a sub-select to give me a list of unique student IDs ... but in 2013, it found that student ID twice so it still counted it twice.

Here is the raw data that is generating the incorrect results because there are 2 records for 2013:

```
RecId   StudentId   Birthdate   AcadYearEnding
39885   16183       11/29/2005  2012
33768   16183       11/29/2005  2013
31020   16183       11/29/2005  2013
59508   16183       11/29/2005  2014
64054   16183       11/29/2005  2015
```

RecId is the unique identifier for the table.

It's possible that what I need is the following (but I would appreciate someone confirming):

```
SELECT COUNT(YEAR(birthdate)) as YearCount, YEAR(birthdate) as BirthYear, AcadYearEnding 
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT(StudentId), birthdate, AcadYearEnding From Test) As Ed
GROUP BY AcadYearEnding 
ORDER BY AcadYearEnding, BirthYear
```

Comment: Can you show us some sample data and expected result, Right now Isnt clear to me where is the duplicated data.

Comment: The data above is actual sample data output after I included a where clause that restricted the output to a single student.  When only looking at a single student, I should have 1 in the first column for every year ... the duplicate row is in 2013.

Comment: Again we need the source data, so we can undestand how the the query produce the output. Also is easy to understand if you put the current output and expected output, so we can spot where the problem is.

Comment: The expected output is to ignore the 2nd row for 2013 and have a count of 1 for each year (for this student ... once the where clause is removed then just count each student once in any given year)

Comment: SELECT COUNT(YEAR(birthdate)) as YearCount, YEAR(birthdate) as BirthYear, AcadYearEnding 
FROM (select distinct(StudentId, AcadYearEnding), <every-other-column> from Enrollment) 
GROUP BY AcadYearEnding 
ORDER BY AcadYearEnding, BirthYear

Comment: @thebignoob If you post that as the answer ... I'll be able to mark it as accepted.

Comment: @thebignoob ... except MySQL-Workbench says Operand should contain 1 column ... so maybe putting distinct (StudentId), followed by the rest of the columns is *more* correct ... but I'm not entirely clear here ...

Comment: What about this: SELECT
  COUNT(DISTINCT StudentId) AS YearCount,
  YEAR(birthdate) AS BirthYear,
  AcadYearEnding
FROM (SELECT
  StudentId,
  AcadYearEnding,
  BirthYear
FROM Enrollment
GROUP BY StudentId,
         AcadYearEnding) AS t
GROUP BY AcadYearEnding
ORDER BY AcadYearEnding, BirthYear;

Comment: @thebignoob That seems to work ... but I don't know if yours or my edit to my original post is "more" correct.  I'm testing with just a single student right now and I'm not sure how to get a larger subset that allows me to test properly but without going to the full 3/4 million records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the proposed (possible) answer I had at the bottom of my question was close ... but not quite right.  The actual answer turned out to be:

```
SELECT (COUNT(YEAR(Birthdate)) As YearCount, Year(Birthdate) As BirthYear, AcadYearEnding
From (SELECT DISTINCT(StudentId), AcadYearEnding, Birthdate From Enrollment) As Ed
GROUP BY BirthYear, AcadYearEnding
ORDER BY AcadYearEnding, BirthYear
```

I've done a count of Birthdate ... which could, and perhaps should have been StudentId but the count is the same either way.

A little more testing, but I appreciate the help getting it this close.

Answer (score 0):

You just want `count(distinct)`, I think:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT StudentId) as YearCount, YEAR(birthdate) as BirthYear, AcadYearEnding 
FROM Enrollment 
WHERE StudentId = 100510230
GROUP BY AcadYearEnding 
ORDER BY AcadYearEnding, BirthYear;
```

Of course, this works without the `WHERE` clause as well:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT StudentId) as YearCount, YEAR(birthdate) as BirthYear, AcadYearEnding 
FROM Enrollment 
GROUP BY AcadYearEnding 
ORDER BY AcadYearEnding, BirthYear;
```

Comment: My concern here (and I haven't tested so I could easily be wrong) is that it would only count that student once ... so with my example data it would only count the student in 2012 ... not in 2013, 2014, and 2015.

Comment: I tested and Distinct(StudentId) doesn't work ... it gives the same output as the incorrect output (with 2 for 2013)

Comment: @NWT_Bob . . . Have you tried running this?  The first query simply cannot return "2" in any row for the first column.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  COUNT(DISTINCT StudentId) AS YearCount,
  YEAR(birthdate) AS BirthYear,
  AcadYearEnding
FROM (SELECT
  StudentId,
  AcadYearEnding,
  BirthYear
FROM Enrollment
GROUP BY StudentId,
         AcadYearEnding) AS t
GROUP BY AcadYearEnding
ORDER BY AcadYearEnding, BirthYear;
```

As you pointed out, you can test this by using limits. No need to use a where clause, because limit will give you more broader scope of testing the query. (Try using LIMIT 10;). Of course, this depends on how much data you have for a particular year.